# What hinge is this?

Tags: doors, hinges

Bit of a newbie to DIY here.

We've moved in to a house that came with a summer house but the double doors were a bit wonky/wouldn't open easily without breaking in the door. I need to get 4 new hinges for the doors but I'm not sure where I can find these ones. I've looked online on UK sites such as Screwfix but as I'm not sure of the particular name I'm not having much luck.

I've attached a drawing (sorry it's the best I can do as my camera isn't working). My Paint skills aren't the best, it's actually a cylinder shape and half of it spins/moves (this is what is broken/doesn't move anymore so it breaks in to the door).

[image]
[image: Picture from appararent duplicate question]
Cheers,
Jack

Comment: Could it be as simple as a need for lubrication? If not, can you remove one of them for long enough to take it to a specialty door hardware place?

Answer (score 4):

Barrel Hinge:

[image]

But note that there's nothing intrinsically wrong with fitting a completely different type of hinge.

You obviously need hinges explicitly intended for outdoor use. Not like [these](http://www.diy.com/search/results/?question=barrel+hinge)

Comment: Also known as a 'lift off hinge'.

Answer (score 0):

It may be a rat tail hinge.

[image]

([Image Source](http://www.dcmitchell.org/rattail_hinge.php))

It doesn't totally look exactly like it, but might be some sort of style of it.