# What hinge is this and where can I buy them in the UK?

Tags: doors, hinges

I need to replace 4 hinges on the doors on our summerhouse.

I have checked in a local hardware store and also I checked in B&Q on the weekend but I couldn't see them in either.

Does anyone know where I can buy these hinges from in the UK?

[image]

Comment: [Possible duplicate](http://diy.stackexchange.com/q/66460/33)

Answer (score 0):

Hard to say exactly who made them because lets face it theres probably millions out there but a company called DCIRON makes very similar one
http://www.dciron.co.uk/hi3/